# wp8: how to submit an update to the app in windows phone store?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store

I have already submitted an app (v1.0) now i wanna update my app. here, i got confusion. There in the windows developer center, two options are available.

`Replace` or `Add New`. Which one I should give to update my existing app ?

Comment: When you select the Apps link from the left pane in dev.windowsphone dashboard you will see update link above the app name, select that

Comment: i done that. while i went to Upload and Describe your XAP, i confused for what i have asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To update your app, you should use `Replace`.

`Add new` allows you to associate multiple XAPs with the same app GUID (for example, if you want to publish two different binaries for a single app: a WP7 version and a WP8 version).

Comment: if i replaced the app, version number is still 1.0.0.0. but i have given 1.1.0.0 in the appmanifest

Comment: Yes, that's normal. The Store version number has to be updated manually.

Comment: I think I had the same problem. I did not choose replace because of the version number issue. I think MS needs to clarify that process on their Phone Dev site. I will try again, but I deleted the old version on the store already. I am guessing those that have an earlier version of my project are out of luck now, on getting the upgraded version.